# How to build Laravel Eloquent for Query String from URL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to Laravel,

the query string from url may be three kind

1. Both "Filter" and "Status": `http://localhost/products?filter=productName&value=Test+Product+1&status=A&action=Filter+Result`
2. "Filter" only and "Status" will be empty: `http://localhost/products?filter=productName&value=Test+Product+1&status=&action=Filter+Result`
3. "Status only and "Filter" will be empty: "Filter" and "Status" `http://localhost/products?filter=&value=&status=A&action=Filter+Result`

Now from Controller i can access the Query string with $inputQ = `Request::input()`

in normal php i can do easy like below

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1 = 1';

if(isset($_REQUEST['filter']) && $_REQUEST['filter'] != '' && $_REQUEST['value'] != ''){
$sql .= 'AND `'.$_REQUEST['filter'].'` = "'.addslashes($_REQUEST['value']).'"';
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['status']) && $_REQUEST['status'] != ''){
$sql .= 'AND `status` = "'.addslashes($_REQUEST['status']).'"';
}

$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Now i need to build Laravel Eloquent please help me.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: @nbin i have read that... my question is i need to add WHERE only when the particular parameter found in URL and if the parameter value is not empty. can you give me some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this? I didn't test it but i guess it should work.

```
$query = DB::table('products')->where(1, '=', 1);

if(Input::has('filter') && Input::has('value')){
    $query->where(Input::get('filter'), '=', Input::get('value'));
}

if(Input::has('status')){
    $query->where('status', '=', Input::get('status'));
}

$res = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i have Model called ProductModel if i use 
$query = ProductModel::where(1, '=', 1); like this it wont works why?

Comment: Does this code work ? i just translated your original code to laravel query. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries. ProductModel::where(...) will not work as it will always return an array of objects or an object.